# ROPC sign-on prompts interactive login

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

Due to the deprecation of some of MS's services, I need to migrate the login method for an **unattended** script. The script is currently set up to log in to the service using Basic Auth username/password, but now must go through something like MSAL to accomplish this.

Again, this will be an **unattended** script so it *cannot* accommodate any interactive prompts.

According to docs, [ROPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#usernamepassword-ropc) (while "not recommended") is documented as not requiring any UI. However, when I try to acquire an access token using this method, I get the following:

```py
>>> app = msal.PublicClientApplication(client_id, authority=f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}')
>>> app.acquire_token_by_username_password(username, passwd, scopes=['Mail.ReadWrite'])
{
  'error': 'invalid_grant',
  'error_description': "AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the 
    application with ID '...' named '...'. Send an interactive authorization request for this
    user and resource.\r\n...",
  'error_codes': [65001],
  ...,
  'suberror': 'consent_required'
}
```

I have also tried to use the API directly:

```
POST
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token

body:
{
  "client_id": "{client_id}",
  "scope": "https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.readwrite",
  "username": "{username}",
  "password": "{password}",
  "grant_type": "password"
}
```

Response same as above.

I have set Delegated permissions in the App registration (but there doesn't seem to be a way to grant admin consent here).

[image: API Permissions Quick View]

The response message suggests this type of request requires an interactive prompt, but the documentation explicitly states this is a non-UI authentication flow.

What am I missing?

Comment: I might need to follow the interactive prompt just once. I think it's asking for the user to consent to the application accessing their account. Hopefully this doesn't have to be repeated very often (or ever). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-error-handling-dotnet#common-net-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

The error usually occurs if the API permissions granted to the Azure AD Application is not consented by the **Global Admin**.

[image]

**To resolve the error**, make sure to Grant Admin Consent to **`mail.readwrite`** permission like below:

[image]

After Granting the Admin Consent, **I am able to generate the access token successfully** like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:f2e61f2e-7340-4f37-9dac-XXXXXX
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.readwrite
username:rukadmin@XXXX.onmicrosoft.com
password:****
grant_type:password
```

[image]

**Alternatively**, you can make use of the below endpoint and sign in as  **`Global Admin`**   and  **Accept**  the consent on behalf of organization like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/adminconsent?client_id=ClientID
```

[image]

You can also make use of Interactive Grant Type and **allow the users to consent to the application accessing their account** by doing the below setting:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Enterprise Application -> User Settings -> Go to Consent and permissions*

[image]